# How To pass Some value from a form page To another using Angular2

Tags: angular

I have two forms (register and login) Features:When the user clicks on the register button the data will be stored in an array that is in register.component.ts after it is redirected to the login page it must connect by its data entered in the register page How to pass the values from forms To another??please ?? PS: I use angular2thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [**`Shared Services`**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) to pass data between components or even you can make use of [**`event emitters`**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/event) for these purpose

Comment: I guess this should be a comment

Comment: yup could be i am surfing via mobile so my bad

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Injectable, Injector} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    data;
    constructor() {}
}
```

in your component

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService ){}
this.dataService.data= somedata;
```

in the other component

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService ){}
somedata= this.dataService.data;
```

remember to register your ap in the providers of the module being used;

```
providers: [DataService]
```

this can be used because the service injected in both components will be a singleton